# custom size integer or float with malloc

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a command line(linux) calculator program in c.
So far, I accomplished the following:-

1. take string input from user and store in char* malloc()
2. validate(check) the string for invalid characters.
3. insert multiply operator between braces. i.e. x(...) = x*(...), (..)(..) = (..)*(..)

finally, it returns a string which is ready to be evaluated.
//following is yet to be implememted

1. evaluate string(expresion) on the basis of BODMAS rule, by manually looping through the string, convert string to integer/float etc...

but the problem is the variable to store the answer, or the result of the evaluation.
I realized that the answer can be very large, beyond the capacity of long int or long double.(which are 4 to 16 bytes which can hold limited digit numbers)

but when the user inputs something like,
4^4^4, or 5^5^5, the answer is very large,
4^4^4 = 155 and 5^5^5 = 2185 digit number according to python3, len(str(5^5^5)),

however this can be simply avoided, by displaying 'infinity' in the screen when the answer is larger than certain digits, i.e beyond the capacity of long double,
**But I want the program to be able to calculate the answer up to 1000 digits long**

So, to solve this, as a beginner in c and new to dynamic allocation, I tried the following lines:

```
float *largef = malloc(4096);
float *largef2 = malloc(sizeof(float) * 1024);
int *largei = malloc(4096);
int *largei2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1024);
```

But, all these line did was declare an array of int or float, which can hold 1024 numbers similar to **int arr[1024];**
and each int in variable largei is just 4 bytes.
This is not what I wanted.

***What I wanted to declare using 'float* largef = malloc(4096);' is to declare the float variable of size 4096 bytes just like the int is 4 bytes and long int is 8 bytes(in 64 bit system) ,
but what the malloc(4096) did was declare an array that holds 1024 floats each of size 4 bytes.***

So how can I dynamically declare a variable of custom size that can hold the number of desired digits. i.e. a variable to store the floats number of upto 1000 digits.

Comment: The C standard does not provide any such built-in features. You must write or use an arbitrary or extended precision math library, such as [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: C don't have arbitrarily large (or small) values. If you want a 16kbit floating point type, you need to implement it yourself, or find a library which can do it for you.